# Finding first order in a single year

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to determine how many new people made an order in 2018. This looks straight forward enough but there is an error with putting calculated fields in the WHERE statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(c.customer_id)
FROM Customer c
LEFT JOIN
    Orders o ON c.customer_id=o.customer_id
WHERE MIN(order_date) > '2017-12-31'
AND MIN(order_date) < '2019-01-01';
```

Comment: @jarlh That won't tell you if it's their first order

Comment: @Barmar, I'm just writing step 2...

Comment: *"Finding first order..."* How is this related with Star Wars postlogy?

Comment: Why do you want to take a count, when all you're doing is finding the first order of a customer during a specific period?

Answer (score 0):

Join with a subquery that finds the customers that were new in 2018.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT o.customer_id)
FROM Orders o
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT customer_id
    FROM Orders
    GROUP BY customer_id
    HAVING MIN(order_date) > '2017-12-31'
) o1 ON o1.customer_id = o.customer_id
WHERE o.order_date < '2019-01-01';
```

There's also no need to join with `Customers`, since the customer ID is in `Orders`.

And the correct way to get the distinct count is `COUNT(DISTINCT o.customer_id)`, not `DISTINCT COUNT(o.customer_id)`.

Comment: I see now why I wouldn't need to join them now and how to properly count distinct but your query throws me an error.

Comment: I forgot the `GROUP BY` in the subquery.

Comment: That didn't change the error

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Sorry, I left the `ON` clause that came from joining with `Customers`. Fixed that.

Comment: This works great now. I guess the only question I have left is why you did not need a MIN in the final WHERE statment

Comment: Because we're joining with customers whose minimum is in that year. So they can't have any earlier orders.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by putting a sequence number to the orders and then selecting the first row for each customer. Although, I'm not really sure why you're performing a count of the orders when you just want to consider the first orders. Nevertheless the below should work just fine.

```sql
SELECT count(res.customer_id) FROM (
   SELECT c.customer_id,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.customer_id ORDER BY o.order_date ASC) row_num 
   FROM Customer c
   LEFT JOIN Orders o ON c.customer_id=o.customer_id
   WHERE o.order_date > '2017-12-31'
   AND o.order_date < '2019-01-01'
) res WHERE res.row_num=1
```